# WP_Query - multiple orderby with a rand field, doesn't work

Tags: wp-query

I have this query:

```
$args = array(
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'post_type'    => 'page',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'meta_query'  => array(
    'relation'    => 'AND',
    'tipo_pagina_clause' => array(
      'key'    => 'tipo_pagina',
      'value'    => 'prodotto',
      'compare'  => '='
    ),
    'tipo_prodotto_clause' => array(
      'key'    => 'tipo_prodotto',
      'compare'  => 'EXISTS',
    ),
    array(
      'key'    => 'brand',
      'value'    => get_the_id(),
      'compare'  => 'LIKE',
    ),
  ),
  'orderby' => array(
    'tipo_prodotto_clause' => 'ASC',
    'post_title' => 'asc',
  ),
);
// query
$prodotti_brand = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Everything works fine, but what I want is 'post_title' = > 'rand', but the 'rand' seems not to work.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is "you can't do that." [Take a look at the Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters).

When using orderby as an array the value can either be `ASC` or `DESC`. If you want to set `rand` you would do so as a key only. That being said, ordering by random will override any other orders, so you won't really get a benefit from ordering by `tipo_prodotto_clause` first.

```
'order' => 'ASC',  
'orderby' => 'rand',
```

Also make sure you take note of the required context for orderby rand:

> Random order. You can also use 'RAND(x)' where 'x' is an integer seed
>   value. **Note an "order" parameter needs to be present for "orderby"**
>   **rand to work.**

A piece of advice: ordering randomly is highly discouraged. The query does not perform well in mysql and has the potential to break caching on a site for every request or not appear to work if caching is less flexible. In fact, [WP Engine has banned its usage by default](https://wpengine.com/support/about-order-by-rand/). Be careful using this. It's usually better to find an alternative solution.